# delete duplicate data in mysql (under big data scenario)

Tags: mysql

I encounter a big problem with big data in MySQL.

We have two big tables, with the same structure, which are used to store English-Chinese parallel corpora. Both of these tables contains records of Ten million grade. There are a lot of duplicate data either within one table and between these two tables (eg. the same English and Chinese content). We want to union the two table to get a clean one by removing data redundancy. However, we find this task not easy with the challenge of big data. The main problem is, there will be memory overflow when we try to union these two table in MySQL.

The data structure of the tables

```
id  ---     en     ---   cn
0   ---   an apple ---  一个苹果
1   ---   an orange---  一个桔子
0   ---   an apple ---  一个苹果
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly edit, vhu.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is often due to the lack of proper indexes on all of the columns that you use in your query. Create the indexes and try again.

For instance, let's say you have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
INNER JOUN t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
WHERE t1.col1 = 10
  AND t2.col2 = 20
```

You will need to create indexes on all the 4 columns in this query:

- t1.id
- t2.t1_id
- t1.col1
- t2.col2

Note: if the t1.id is a primary key, then it has an index and you don't need to create one for it, so just create indexes on the other 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Racil! We will try it tomorrow ~ I am sure that it will work!